# Save non-repeating objects in array React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to add information (objects) in an array, but I have not been able to save data that is not repetitive (unique data):

```
<div>
    {
      Labels.map(l => (
         <div onClick={() => handleAddList(l)} key={l.id} style={{ backgroundColor: l.color 
          }}>
             {l.name}
         </div>
     ))
    }
</div>
```

This is my function in which I save the data

```
const handleAddList = (label) => {
        setLabelsList([...labelsList, {
            color: label.color, id: label.id, name: label.name, textColor: label.textColor
        }])
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `findIndex` function to see if the label exists in side your labels list or not.
The way you can use it is :

```
const labelIndex = labelsList.findIndex((labelInSide) => labelInSide.id === label.id);
if(labelIndex < 0) {setLabelsList([...labelsList, {
        color: label.color, id: label.id, name: label.name, textColor: label.textColor
    }])}
```

I think this should help you.